# Problems with refresh div with Jquery (append) and variables

Tags: jquery, ajax, variables

After i have recovery a date with a datePicker, i would like to post the news attributs of a object in a special div in my JSP.

The problem is that all the page is reloaded in my div.

This is a part of my scprit about the Jquery and Ajax. I want to show the attribut of "Mission" :

```
$('#datepicker').change(function() {
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '${pageContext. request. contextPath}/convoyeur/listeMission/' + $('#datepicker').val().replace('/','-').replace('/','-'),
      error:function(msg, string){
          alert( "Error !: " + string );
          },
      success: function(mission){
          // On remet les champs à vide
          $("#tab").empty().hide;
          //On remplit les champs de la du tableau avec la date saisie
          $("#tab").append(mission);



      }
    });
});
```

And then the code about my JSP :

```
<p>Choisir une date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

<div  id="tab" class="container">

<div  class="content">
    <table class="table table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="center-td">Date d'execution</th>
                <th class="center-td">client</th>
                <th class="center-td">site depart</th>
                <th class="center-td">site arrivee</th>
                <th class="center-td">Vehicule</th>
                <th class="center-td">commentaire</th>
                <th class="center-td"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach var="mission" items="${listMission}" >
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${mission.date }"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${mission.nomClient }"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${mission.siteDepart.adresse }"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${mission.siteArrivee.adresse }"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${mission.vehicule.modele }"/></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${mission.commentaire }"/></td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I think that the mistake is on the line :

```
$("#tab").append(mission)
```

but i'm not sure.

Thanks you

Comment: You want to display in your tabs all the missions corresponding to the selected date ? In this case, you don't need to empty your div but just the table rows. And for each object in your result data, add a row to the table

Comment: Yes, but at first i have to clean the tab with the mission, because by default I post the missions of the day.

Comment: And then when I choose a date, I just want to post the missions of this day and not the missions of the other days

Comment: I don't now if  I have enough clear?

Comment: yes you are ! (les commentaires en Français aussi ^^). Create a simple function that make 3 steps. 1st : empty the table `$("#matable").find("tbody>tr").remove()` then, 2nd step, call your ajax method. Last step, in the ajax callback, for each object in your result, create a row and insert it to the body of your table `var ligne = $("<tr>"); /*fill your <tr> with td's*/ then, $("#matable).find("tbody").append(ligne);`. Of course you must add an ID to your table.

Comment: Thans to you, but i found another solution.

Comment: The problem camme from my JSP mapping, when Ajax returns the data, I did'nt change the redirection of my Controller. Now I have two JSP and in the second I just put the code of my tab and it works! Thanks you anyway!!